# Почему значения типа byte становятся отрицательными при приведении к int?

Tags: java, byte

Не могу понять, почему в метод `print()` приходят отрицательные числа, и мне приходится к ним прибавлять `256` для последующего перевода в двоичную систему?
Как этого избежать, или как с этим правильно работать?

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] ip = new byte[]{(byte) 192, (byte) 168, 1, 2};
        byte[] mask = new byte[]{(byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 254, 0};
        print(ip);          //11000000 10101000 00000001 00000010    
        print(mask);        //11111111 11111111 11111110 00000000
        print(netAddress);  //11000000 10101000 00000000 00000000
    };

    public static void print(byte[] bytes) {
        for (int i : bytes) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (i < 0) i = (256 + i); // --- почему приходится использовать костыль?
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                sb.append(i % 2);
                i /= 2;
            }
            sb.reverse();
            System.out.print(sb+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    };
}
```

Comment: Дык это и так понятно, а почему так происходит-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё, я понял. Дело в том что тип byte от -128 до 127 и всё что больше 127 идет в минус. Например (int) 128 = (byte) -128, а (int) 129 = (byte) -127.